# Configure Arduino Portable IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, installation

I am following [this page](https://www.elektormagazine.com/news/how-to-make-arduino-portable-and-future-proof) (among others similar) about creating a portable Arduino IDE.

Though the steps are declared as easy...

1. Downloading the v.1.8.13 *Windows ZIP file for non admin install*,
2. Creating the `portable` folder,
3. Executing the arduino.exe file.

...I got stuck with this error:

> `This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted`

I uninstalled v.1.8.13, then installed v.1.6.0, and never had any problems with JRE, until now.

What I am missing?

Comment: I'm using zip files since forever without issues. JRE is packed in subdirectory, so it should be working without it installed on OS level. That portable directory is great, never heard about it before.

Comment: @KIIV So, how shoud I use a packaged JRE in the Arduino Unzipped folder? What am I missing?

Comment: Just unpack arduino ide, jump into its directory and start Arduino.exe. It's expecting to have java in subdirectory. Btw, when I renamed java subdirectory, I've got exactly the same error message. (another way might be creating symlink to the system java instalation directory, or find out how to create Arduino.exe without that java bundling)

Comment: [These instructions](https://gist.github.com/summermk/2e808afcded695cc6f7f94ed69b15eb7) are interesting. Mainly section "Issues / Solution #1" - "When I used default Windows 'extract all' it didn't create half the folders which included java.".